# General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 62-IONIC emulate Android

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, sdk, ionic4

General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 62

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

Version JDK 18.0.2
Version Gradle: 7.5.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`JDK 18` is unsupported. You will need to downgrade, you can try version `16`, `17` or `11`.

Comment: JDK 18 is supported as of gradle 7.5 according to the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) and the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html).

Comment: I know it's, but some features are Deprecated just try version 11 and it will work for you.

Comment: oh my goodness thankyou. did they get an intern to write that matrix???